# Defining a generic parameter with a default value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, python-typing

Let's say I have the following code:

```py
from typing import Literal, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T", bound=str)

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def foo(self, arg: T = "foo") -> T:
        return arg
```

The idea is that I have a generic class with a concrete method that takes a string, but the child classes can define a more restrictive input than any string, for example this class will only accept `"bar"`:

```py
class Bar(Foo[Literal["bar"]]):
    pass
```

However, the original code doesn't pass any type checker. Both mypy and pyright complain. The mypy error is:

```
test.py:6: error: Incompatible default for argument "arg" (default has type "str", argument has type "T")
```

I would have thought this would be okay, because `T` has an upper bound which is a string. However I think the issue is that the default argument "foo" no longer makes sense if the child class accepts only "bar". How then can I define `T` such that it must always allow the literal `"foo"`, but the child class can also define additional strings it will accept?

Comment: You could I guess make new type that is a union between T and your litteral ?

Comment: Oh, good point, I can do `ArgType = Union[T, Literal["foo"]]` and then `def foo(self, arg: ArgType = "foo") -> ArgType`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to a suggestion from comments, consider using `typing.overload`:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Literal, TypeVar, Generic, overload
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

T = TypeVar("T", bound=str | Literal["foo"])


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    @overload
    def foo(self, arg: T) -> T:
        ...

    @overload
    def foo(self) -> Literal["foo"]:
        ...

    def foo(self, arg: T | Literal["foo"] = "foo") -> T | Literal["foo"]:
        return arg


class Bar(Foo[Literal["bar"]]):
    pass


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(Bar().foo("bar"))  # Revealed type is "Literal['bar']"
    reveal_type(Bar().foo())  # Revealed type is "Literal['foo']"
```

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that I have a generic class with a concrete method that
> takes a string, but the child classes can define a more restrictive
> input than any string

This is a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), so mypy and pyright are correct to refuse it. A child class needs to accept anything that the parent class accepts, otherwise you can't freely substitute a child class for the parent class. You *can* do the opposite though; a child class is allowed to be *more* permissive than the parent.