# TypeVar including Tuple[()] for argument with empty-tuple value makes mypy unhappy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, mypy, default-value

Why doesn't mypy [version 0.991, python 3.9.10] like the first two examples below:

```
from typing import List, Tuple, TypeVar, Union, Optional

Context1 = TypeVar('Context1',List[str],Tuple[str, ...])
Context2 = TypeVar('Context2',Tuple[str, ...],List[str])

Ctxt = Union[List[str],Tuple[str,...]]

def foo1(c: Context1 = ()) -> None:
  pass

def foo2(c: Context2 = ()) -> None:
  pass

def baz(c: Ctxt = ()) -> None:
  pass
```

I get the following errors:

```
>: mypy --explicit-package-bases hack.py
hack.py:8: error: Incompatible default for argument "c"
  (default has type "Tuple[]", argument has type "List[str]")  [assignment]
hack.py:11: error: Incompatible default for argument "c"
  (default has type "Tuple[]", argument has type "List[str]")  [assignment]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Note in particular the curious fact that `Tuple[()]` has dropped out of the argument type.

Using e.g. Optional[Context1] gives comparable errors.

I clearly have not understood how `TypeVar` arguments are treated.  I thought there was essentially no difference between `Ctxt` and `Context1`.

Note that for my purposes what's important here is that my TypeVars have multiple explicit allowed alternative type arguments, rather than a single named argument.  So at least some of my problem is not addressed by  [Defining a generic parameter with a default value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73456624/defining-a-generic-parameter-with-a-default-value-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining a generic parameter with a default value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73456624/defining-a-generic-parameter-with-a-default-value-in-python)

Comment: In addition to proposed dupe, here's [relevant mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737). And sure `TypeVar` is not even similar to `Union` in your case. Your code doesn't need type variable at all: when they appearonly once in function definition outside of class generic in the same variable, they are useless. Type variables are used for cases when function can accept arg of type `T` (probably with some restrictions - `bound=` or variants) **and** produce output with `T` in type *or* other arg depending on `T`.

Comment: You also allow `list` or `tuple`, but not some variable where type is `list | tuple` (and it's not known which of them). Generally `collections.abc.Sequence` should be preferred, if you don't need exactly list or tuple, but can live with `np.array`, `array.array`, etc. - or maybe even `Iterable` or `Collection` to accept more possible iterables.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, thanks, but no, I don't think your first reference helps, because my TypeVars include explicit alternative allowed values...
But your second answer is very helpful.  I'm still baffled by the error message, in that the relevant alternative (that is, `Tuple[str, ...]`, is being ignored (you have to scroll to the right to see the relevant bit of the messages).

Comment: This may be really confusing, but `mypy` always reports like this, when something is wrong with one (or more) of typevar variants. If you add a third option, 2 errors will be reported for every line ([like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=ff3876c09a256f665d6644beca9de753)). Also, please note that `typing.List` and `typing.Tuple` are deprecated as of python3.9, if you're learning - I'd recommend to use more modern way (built-in `list` and `tuple` are subscriptable).

Comment: Ah, OK, little steps forward here.  And thanks for the link to the mypy Playground!
Remaining question:  so the problem is with the Tuple(str,...) entry in the list, but what's wrong with it?  It is accepted, and works, as part of the Union further down...

Comment: The problem is with an attempt to specify default for argument, which type contains a TypeVar - this is just a mypy limitation (see the link to issue tracker above). There's nothing really wrong with any of entries - only mypy implementation bug plus improper choice of outer type. You don't need TypeVar here, because it appears in the signature only once, but if its usage was justified - you'd have to use overloads instead. That's why your Union type works as expected.